# how to pass that type json data in adapter class in retrofit?

Tags: android, adapter, retrofit

How to parsing that response in retrofit to adapter class and get that images and like object in adapter class

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "album_id": "82",
            "album_name": "test",
            "date": "2016-11-11",
            "images": [
                {
                    "photo": "../media/images/wedding/IMG-20161111-WA0016.jpg",
                    "like": "0"
                },
                {
                    "photo": "../media/images/wedding/IMG-20161111-WA0010.jpg",
                    "like": "0"
                }
            ],
            "email": "maci@gmail.com",
            "wedd_key": "IEBF2Y",
            "status": "Bride"
        }
    ],
    "code": "100"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Call api Retrofit getResponse() will give callback. see below code.

```
Call<AlbumObject> call = apiService.getTopRatedMovies(API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<AlbumObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AlbumObject> call, Response<AlbumObject> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            List<AlbumObject> movies = response.body().getResults();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new Adapter(movies, R.layout.list_item_movie, getApplicationContext()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AlbumObject> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
```

onResponse will give callback then set that List to your adapter. For more detail see this tutorial [Retrofit Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/)